# Segments producing active class

Tags: css, navigation, segments

I have a simple unordered list nav, it displays an active list item depending on segment_1.
Within that unordered list I have another unordered list with a class of 'sub'.
For some reason, all list items display as active too in IE7, but not active class is within that list item.

I know its not fully an EE question, but has anyone ever seen this?
Code is below:

```
<ul><li class="program"><a href="/program/" title="Program Overview">Program Overview</a></li>
<li class="tour active"><a href="/tour" title="Take a Tour">Take a Tour</a></li>
<ul class="sub">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="tour" limit="10" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" entry_id="not 41" dynamic="off"}
    <li><a href="{url_title_path=tour}" title="{title}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your second ul isn't nested correctly. It should be inside the closing li tag of the second li. Try moving it there and see.

Comment: Nope, didnt do the trick.

Comment: Hi Tad, can we see a public sample page with your css? It might help us figure out what's going on in IE

Comment: What does your CSS rule that styles the `.active` class look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a CSS issue I think. Try a CSS selector like ul > li.active to make sure it's targeting just the first tier li.

Comment: yep it was a css issue.  i didnt think it was an ee one, but wanted to post.